# ng-options custom sort angular select menu for particular value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select name="region" id="region" ng-options="id as name for (id, name) in regions[entry.country]" ng-model="entry.region"  class="form-control select-styled" required></select>
```

I wanna use some kind of filter or custom sort to sort regions if entry.region is equal to Japnese. Currently options are displayed by key, and i wanna sort them by value (japanese alphabet) ? Any idea how to start?

Comment: share more code please ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `filter` to check what's the region and then apply sorting.

Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mL7FAoOlw4j02jhxpbnT?p=preview) I've made for you.